# .htaccess redirect request to subdomain subfolder with ssl

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, subdomain

I would like to redirect all requests from `http://sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com/en/`.

For example, a customer visiting `http://sub.domain.com/test` will be redirected to `https://sub.domain.com/en/test/` through htaccess rule.

What rule is needed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```